# doesnot show keyword exist?what is wrong in the program?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
<script>
var words=['abstract',  'arguments',    'await',    'boolean',
'break',    'byte',     'case',     'catch',
'char',     'class',    'const',    'continue',
'debugger',     'default',  'delete',   'do',
'double',   'else',     'enum',     'eval',
'expor',    'extends',  'false',    'final',
'finally',  'float',    'for',  'function',
'goto',     'if',   'implements',   'import',
'in',   'instanceof',   'int',  'interface',
'let',  'long',     'native',   'new',
'null',     'package',  'private',  'protected',
'public',   'return',   'short',    'static',
'super',    'switch',   'synchronized',     'this',
'throw',    'throws',   'transient',    'true',
'try',  'typeof',   'var',  'void',
'volatile',     'while',    'with',     'yield'];
var length=words.length;
var input=prompt("enter keywords")
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    //alert(words[i]);
    if(input==words[i]){
        alert("keyword exist");
    }
    else{
            alert("not found");
            //break;
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

doesnot show keyword exist?what is wrong in the program?

Comment: FYI java !== js

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you make a *final* decision based on the *first* word in the list that doesn't match. You'll see that if you enter the keyword `abstract`, which will result in a message stating you found it, then making a final decision on the *second* word in the list.

What you need to do is to check *all* the words, logging and breaking if found and, only if *none* matched do you output the "Not found" message.

Something like this should suffice:

```
var length = words.length;
var input = prompt("Enter word to check")

var foundIt = false;             // Assume not found.
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {   // Check EVERY word.
    if (input == words[i]) {     // If match,
        alert("Found it");       //   log and exit loop.
        foundIt = true;
        break;
    }                            // Otherwise check other words.
}

// If NO word in list matched, log the fact.

if (! foundIt) {
    alert("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = false;
var words=['abstract', 'arguments', 'await', 'boolean', 'break', 'byte', 
'case', 'catch', 'char', 'class', 'const', 'continue', 'debugger', 'default', 
'delete', 'do', 'double', 'else', 'enum', 'eval', 'expor', 'extends', 'false', 
'final', 'finally', 'float', 'for', 'function', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'import', 
'in', 'instanceof', 'int', 'interface', 'let', 'long', 'native', 'new', 'null', 
'package', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'return', 'short', 'static', 'super', 
'switch', 'synchronized', 'this', 'throw', 'throws', 'transient', 'true', 'try', 
'typeof', 'var', 'void', 'volatile', 'while', 'with', 'yield']; 

var len = words.length;
var inp = prompt ("enter keywords");
for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
    alert(words[i]);
    if (inp == words[i]){
        alert ("keyword found");
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!flag)
    alert ("not found");
```

}

try to run the above script.

Answer (score 0):

You may change it to something like this:

```
var words=[
    'abstract', 'arguments',    'await',    'boolean',
    'break',    'byte',         'case',     'catch',
    'char',     'class',        'const',    'continue',
    'debugger', 'default',      'delete',   'do',
    'double',   'else',         'enum',     'eval',
    'expor',    'extends',      'false',    'final',
    'finally',  'float',        'for',      'function',
    'goto',     'implements',   'if',       'import',
    'in',       'instanceof',   'int',      'interface',
    'let',      'long',         'native',   'new',
    'null',     'package',      'private',  'protected',
    'public',   'return',       'short',    'static',
    'super',    'synchronized', 'switch',   'this',
    'throw',    'throws',       'true',     'transient',
    'try',      'typeof',       'var',      'void',
    'volatile', 'while',        'with',     'yield'];

var input="try";

var idx = words.indexOf(input);
console.log("Keyword [" + input + "] " + (idx == -1 ? "not " : "") + "found");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the entire array list, you are just validating the first array item.

Please find the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/w1an76kL/) with updated logic.

```
var words = ['abstract', 'arguments', 'await', 'boolean',
  'break', 'byte', 'case', 'catch',
  'char', 'class', 'const', 'continue',
  'debugger', 'default', 'delete', 'do',
  'double', 'else', 'enum', 'eval',
  'expor', 'extends', 'false', 'final',
  'finally', 'float', 'for', 'function',
  'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'import',
  'in', 'instanceof', 'int', 'interface',
  'let', 'long', 'native', 'new',
  'null', 'package', 'private', 'protected',
  'public', 'return', 'short', 'static',
  'super', 'switch', 'synchronized', 'this',
  'throw', 'throws', 'transient', 'true',
  'try', 'typeof', 'var', 'void',
  'volatile', 'while', 'with', 'yield'
];
var length = words.length,
  input = prompt("enter keywords"),
  found = false;
  console.clear();
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (input == words[i]) {
    found = true;
    console.log("Found");
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  console.log("Not Found");
}
```